# Different storeviews or websites in subfolders

Tags: configuration, magento-1, multistore, url

A client wants his multistore shop to be set up like this:

- http://www.domain1.org/de/ -> website 1, store view 1
- http://www.domain1.org/en/ -> website 1, store view 2
- http://www.domain1.ch/de/  -> website 2, store view 3
- http://www.domain1.ch/fr/  -> website 2, store view 4
- http://www.domain1.ch/it/  -> website 2, store view 5
- ...

This is an example but there may be many more different subfolders.
What is the best approach to handle different subfolders for different store views / websites?

I know that one solution is to create subfolders called `de`, `en` etc. and copy the index.php and .htaccess into the corresponding subfolders.

There also may be some workarounds (symlinks for index.php, vHost configuration instead of using .htaccess) to minimise file duplication but I'd like to find a solution where I don't have to do any changes in the file system but just handle everything by configuration.

---

**UPDATE**

We verified with Enterprise support that the best way to do this is by creating subfolders.

We ended up doing it like this:

- Create a "languagefolders" directory
- Created a copy of index.php inside the directory along with an adjusted .htaccess and symlinks to the Magento folders (app/, errors/, ...)
- Created symlinks "de", "en" etc. inside the Magento root directory pointing to the "languagefolders" directory

This way we can add a new language by creating a new symlink (e.g. "fr").

Comment: We did just this only to find that the website cannot find any product or category (Magento 404 / no route to page). Did you encounter this also?

Comment: Not as far as I remember, sorry. Did you re-create all indexes?

Comment: We use nginx and an update is necessary to the conf to make it work. I will update my comment

Comment: 2 more strange things. 1) /checkout returns a 404 and 2) the language chooser: if I click english, then click english again we see that the uri keeps adding /en/en/en/etc .... what did you choose as base url? domain.com/en or didi you keep it as domain.com

Comment: We chose domain.com/en/.

Comment: @MatthiasZeis I am asking some info apart from your post, i am created multi-store, using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/. I am using the same theme for both stores, how can i change header and footer for my second store, pls keep in mind same theme. What is the use of symlinks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very easy to serve multiple domains/paths based on URLs. As mentioned, *the easiest setup (configuration-only) is possible when the unique `core/store` codes can be used in the path as subfolders*. This requires one of the following:

1. Visitors are linked to the correct subfolder path initially
2. Visitors are served a landing page from which they select their store and receive a cookie
3. Some mechanism is used to set the run type and run code prior to PHP handling the response

Regarding #3: since 1.4 Magento, made it possible to allow the Web server to determine the running context (**website** or **store**) as well as the particular code which should be used. From *index.php*:

```php
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Whereas environment variables are used to initialize the application, it's possible to influence the system prior to PHP even spinning up. With Apache and `mod_rewrite` this can be done for subfolders with a bit of trickery:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:deutsch]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
```

Apache is twitchy with environment variables and subfolders, as demonstrated by [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10128290/833795). The initial two lines result in `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = 'deutsch';` while the latter two lines provide the needed `$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = 'deutsch';`. There are numerous other tricks, but the above has bitten me before.

***The end goal should be initial detection as much as is reasonable (geoip + multi-language concerns) while getting the user to set the store cookie which can be used to bypass/step through the logic in subsequent requests.***

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Doing it this way, I can initialise the store views but I always get the Magento 404 page ("Whoops, our bad"). I set the base URL to http://www.domain1.org/en/, http://www.domain.org/de/ and so on. Skin URL, Media URL etc. are set to http://www.domain.org/(skin|media|...)
Please note that the correct pages are returned if I use the normal "copy index.php and .htaccess" approach.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it gets the closest to what we tried to accomplish (even when we solved it a little bit different for our special requirements).

Comment: Really surprised that "Add Store Code to URL" setting didn't work.

Comment: Store codes have to be unique. How should it work with several store views all ending with de/, fr/ or en/?

Comment: I think I missed the replicated store codes, though I think I was assuming some Web server-based rewriting (e.g. `mode_rewrite`) based on `HTTP_HOST` + subfolder level 1.

Comment: How can this be done in Magento 2.1.12 ?

Comment: @Jai That's a new question.

Answer (score 9):

If the indented URLs (subfolders) can have the same name like the store codes (why not?), you can simply enabled `Configuration > Web > Url options >  Add Store Code to Urls`.

Comment: Correct, then you will not even need subfolders. as long as url rewriting is enabled, Magento will know that "en" is a storeview code and not look for a subfolder.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that Magento allows only one store code "de" in a Magento installation. So if you have several websites with the same languages you have to use different storecodes, e.g. de_de, de_en, ...

Comment: Rouven got it. The problem is that you cannot have multiple stores with the same store code.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that - as Rouven said - you cannot have two store views using the same store code.

Comment: I confirm that Rouven got it right. A bug was reported to Magento. Because in these modern environments with more multistores this should work. However, do you think it would be possible to make the setting `Add store codes to url` a storeview setting? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60686/multi-multistore-multiple-brands-multiple-languages-setting-store-view-code = suppose there 1 multistore with sep domains, the other uses /en and /fr

Answer (score 3):

we ended up doing exactly that

We verified with Enterprise support that the best way to do this is by creating subfolders.

> We ended up doing it like this:
>
> - Create a "languagefolders" directory
> - Created a copy of index.php inside the directory along with an adjusted .htaccess and symlinks to the Magento folders (app/, errors/,
>     ...)
> - Created symlinks "de", "en" etc. inside the Magento root directory pointing to the "languagefolders" directory
>
> This way we can add a new language by creating a new symlink (e.g.
>   "fr").

In the backend we set the store `base url` to `domain.com/en`

If you use nginx an update is necessary to your location processing to process index.php also in the new sub folder. This needs to be done for every new translation folder

Comment: snh_nl Is there a chance you explain what your last 2 lines mean? I m having the same problem you said before but I can't understand: If  you use nginx an update is necessary to your location processing to process index.php also in the new sub folder. This needs to be done for every new translation folder. I m using nginx and I m trying to do the same.
Thanks

Comment: `location @rewrite {
       rewrite /(../)? /$1index.php;
       }`

Answer (score 2):

There is an [entry in official Magento knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) that describes exactly that.

In case you are working with Apache, make sure all Virtual Host entries (for each domain) are pointing to the same document root where your Magento installation lies. That's for multiple domains.

The next (and last) thing is the **.htaccess** in same Magento installation folder. .htaccess is a powerful directory-level configuration file where you can set rules-actions per each server request. So you will need to handle all different (sub)domains/folders actions there and set the correct server variables that Magento uses at initializing stage.

After you're done with server configuration, you will have to set different base paths for each of the store in Magento admin (system - configuration - general - web).

So make sure you follow the official guide (which is also the preferred way) and things should work smoothly.

Comment: The question was not about multiple domains.

Comment: Question was about multistore setup WITH MULTIPLE DOMAINS (.org and .ch are different domains). Not that it matters though, because the provided answer describes a solution to multistore setup regardless if you have multiple domains, subdomains or just different subfolders for each of your stores.

Comment: But the focus was on paths for the store views, it did not sound like the domains were a problem. Anyway, after your edit I changed my vote.

Comment: Exactly, the problem isn't that multiple domains have to be used but that several stores must share the same path / "subfolder" which isn't possible by adding store codes to the URL.

Answer (score -2):

First you have to do some configuration in the Magento admin panel, then create a subdirectory, and move the index.php and the .htaccess to the subdirectory, and make some minor changes to the index.php.

[Here](http://blog.codexpedia.com/magento/how-to-add-a-new-store-in-the-same-magento-code-base) is a complete example of how to do this.