# What is the best strategy to integrate WordPress inside of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, wordpress

I am looking for the best way to integrate WordPress inside of Magento.

First I would like WordPress to use the Header and Footer of Magento.

Second, I would like it to be possible for a user to search on Magento, and WordPress at the same time. And not be stuck. Having to search input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends.
You've choice :

- Use a dedicated module like the Fishpig's module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html
- Use JSONP to purpose to load the header and footer

If you use the Fishpig module (which is a good module) you can use http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-wordpress-integrated-search-4394.html

The latest solution is to develop your own WordPress integration on Magento :)

Comment: Yah... I am in trouble. I only have a week. :\

Comment: My problem with this Fichpig's module is that I am not sure it works for a multi-languages WordPress blog. So I am not sure it will work with this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: You can use WordPress Multisites and integrate them into Magento with the FishPig Multisite extension - http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/multisite/

Comment: Is there any module through which I can integrate wordpress in such a way that my store customers can comment on a forum created by wordpress without login to wordpress ?

Answer (score 23):

I've used the Fishpig module on a load of sites, have bought the paid for plugins and have been happily promoting it for years.  However, I am not using it any more.  It does what it does well, but what it does is run everything through Magento.

Let's face it, the client takes one look at a Wordpress site and suddenly starts getting creative.  'We can do this in Wordpress!', 'We can do that in the Wordpress install!'.  You have to keep explaining to them that normally, yes that is easy to do in Wordpress....but that their Wordpress installation isn't normal as it is all running through the Magento itself and that changes everything.

So your bank of custom Wordpress widgets won't work, 3rd party Wordpress plugins won't work.  Themes and theme options won't work.  Unless you do a load of work converting and assimilating them into the Fishpig module.

A much better approach in my opinion is to go the way of James Kemp (http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/) or Richard Feraro (http://wordpress.org/plugins/mage-enabler/).  They both take the same approach, allowing you to access the Mage object from Wordpress and pull whatever you want from Magento into your Wordpress theme. If you look at the plugins though, they are very simple and don't involve much code.

They both require a modification to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php` as both Wordpress and Magento have a `function __()` method declared.  There are detailed notes about it on both plugin authors sites though and it is very easy. After that you can get stuck in.

It's so simple, here's an example using the James Kemp plugin. You can have a stripped down Wordpress theme with a `header.php` like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <?php the_block("head"); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Which pulls your whole Magento head block into the Wordpress header.  Perfect, no duplication, no additional work. Note I added `wp_head()` because if you add in Wordpress plugins they'll potentially use that as a hook and it's good practice to have that in your Wordpress `header.php` file.

Same goes for footer.php;

```
    <?php the_block("footer"); ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

And there's your Magento footer block in Wordpress.  The rest is up to you but you've got the freedom to add as much additional stuff into your Wordpress install as you like without any constraints.

**Edit - May 14**

Since I wrote this I've also started using Wordpress as the CMS and pulling data back into Magento using this Wordpress plugin - JSON API plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

To give you a code example - the code below pulls the requisite entries in Wordpress for a custom post type called event, accesses a custom field in those posts called eventdate puts them all in an array, sorts it by date and outputs a list of all the events with a link to each event page in Wordpress install.  I've used it in the main navigation of a Magento site in a dropdown, it works really well.  Wordpress is due to have a JSON API added to the core but as of yet it's not been released.

```
<ul>
    <?php 

    $events = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/blog/?json=get_posts&post_type=event'));

    $eventList = array();

    foreach ( $events->posts as $event_item ) :

        $arrayDate = date("ymdHi", strtotime($event_item->custom_fields->eventdate[0] ));

        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Title'] = $event_item->title;
        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Date'] = date('l jS F', strtotime($event_item->custom_fields->eventdate[0] ));
        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Link'] = $event_item->url;


    endforeach; 

    // Key reverse sort to get events in date order
    ksort($eventList);

    foreach ($eventList as $eventItem) : 

        echo '<li><a href="'. $eventItem['Link'] .'">'. $eventItem['Title'] .' - '. $eventItem['Date'] .'</a></li>';

    endforeach;     

    ?>
</ul>
```

**Edit - Oct 15**

I recently had to try and use this integration method in a multi store that was using the same country code subdirectories as in this question by Matthias Zeis;

[Different storeviews or websites in subfolders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195/different-storeviews-or-websites-in-subfolders)

I did consider trying the Fishpig multistore extension for this but in the end I asked a question on SO -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613815/htaccess-wordpress-under-magento-site-with-multi-language-sub-directories

I've put the answer up there, it uses server environment variables and some Wordpress filters.  I've added the .htaccess and Nginx server blocks too to help.

Also, for anyone who deploys their Magento site using Capistrano and shivers at the prospect of having the constantly updated Wordpress core and plugins polluting their repo I wrote a blog post showing how you can just move the whole lot into the shared directory in Capistrano 3 and only have your Wordpress theme in the repo;

http://www.mcnab.co/blog/wordpress-git-and-capistrano-v3/

Comment: Which of the WordPress plugins that you are proposing are you using the most? Also my Magento is in multiple languages.

Comment: I'm not proposing any plugins - I do loads of Wordpress work so I use many plugins depending on need.  To give a good example though, Fishpig sells the Contact Form 7 plugin which will work with the Fishpig extension.  But it can't hold a candle to the mighty Gravity Forms plugin which is untouchable for forms related stuff (something I find a nightmare in Magento).

Comment: I have edited the original answer as I realise I was talking too much about plugins.  What I was really referring to was Wordpress customisation :)

Comment: The only thing that I think we need is Facebook comments instead of WordPress normal comment form. Is it possible with Fishpig module?

Comment: Not without work.  You can add Facebook comments into your Magento site easily enough, Fishpig sells the Disqus comments plugin, which is a much better way of managing your comments than through Facebook if you ask me. http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/disqus/

Comment: My boss does not like Disqus for some reason. So I am stuck with Facebook comments. I am thinking about going with one of the other solutions you have proposed so that I can add FB comments.

Comment: this is a great answer as you get across the relative pros and cons of using Fishpig vs the Kemp plugin and so on. I have used the latter a few times and it works really well. Fishpig is good though for its power if you have the budget to buy the extra features.

Comment: @boobyWomack - Cheers.  I actually wrote another answer recently about pulling data back out of Wordpress and into Magento usins json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433228/adding-wordpress-functionality-to-parts-of-a-clients-website/23433925#23433925, I'll update my answer now with it.

Comment: @McNab best advice I ever received on stackexchange.. thanks

Comment: @s_h - best comment I've ever received on stackexchange! Cheers :)

Comment: @JamesKemp - thanks for the plugin! Made my life a lot easier when it came to integrating the two systems. Cheers.

Comment: @McNab thanks for great post, really helped me. I used an observer in a custom module tro integrate WP and magento main navigation by pulling JSON wp menu data from REST API and adding into existing magento main nav in the observer. Works great in Magento! BUT when I pull the_block('header') inside wordpress as per the plugin insttuctions, the wordpress menu links are missing. So ironically my WP pages have the magento nav but not wordpress - gah!  Do you have any insight into this? I'm wondering if you had to do the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 6):

Fishpig's WordPress integration extension.  It's free, works well, integrates the theme.  Doesn't integrate the search.  But it's the best integration method we're aware of.

Comment: But does it work with multiple languages? Multi-site...

Comment: You can now integrate search also: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/integrated-search/

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use wordgento:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/tristar-wordgento/

I have used this for my blog and worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free Magento plugin that allows you to use the content created with wordpress inside your Magento design. This allows you to use the power of the Wordpress blog and content inside your store. I dont know if the search is also in the wordpress content. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html for more details.