# Wordpress on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

We have a magento site with the URL (let's say) ourstore.com and also a wordpress hosted blog using the blog.ourstore.com url (we use an extra dns record here). For SEO purposes we would like to run our blog using the ourstore.com/blog url. Is there a way to achieve this other than installing wordpress on the magento instance? Because we do this for SEO, i think redirect (302) or any kind of url_rewrite solution does not really work now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are lots plugins available for your problem. please go through with below links, that may clear your problem statement or may you get result in better way.

[What is the best strategy to integrate WordPress inside of Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-integrate-wordpress-inside-of-magento)

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-1.html

https://www.cminds.com/best-ways-to-integrate-wordpress-and-magento/