# Integrating Magento2 and Wordpress on different servers

Tags: magento2, wordpress, integration

Im looking into integrating Magento2 with Wordpress.
Most importantly, Id like the wordpress site to have the same header and footer as the Magento site. Ideally, Id like my marketing team to easily show Magento products on the Wordpress Blog.

I have seen many plugins or code that could solve this.

However, the Wordpress and Magento are on different servers.

I am very familiar with Wordpress, I am just now learning Magento. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A different server is not a "big" problem when integrating Magento 2 with another system. M2 provides a list of built-in REST APIs:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html

We can use Extension: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/

This question is old, but we should take a look: [What is the best strategy to integrate WordPress inside of Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-integrate-wordpress-inside-of-magento?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but for future readers, FishPig's [Magento WordPress Integration](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) can now integrate when WordPress is installed on a different server.