# Magento : How to hide the default Store View code from the url

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, url

The site has 2 languages: English and French, represented by 2 store views. French is the default one. For our SEO efforts we need to have the following urls:

```
French - http://www.domain.com/category/product
English - http://www.domain.com/en/category/product
```

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Add Store Codes to URL is the all or nothing setting. i turn it off for the default store only. I’ve done a lot of searching through the forums and wiki but there’s nothing on the subject.

Please any sugestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By chance I worked on this same problem recently and created [this store codes extension](https://github.com/Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes).  It works by inserting itself into the router chain, something most module devs aren't even aware of.  Instructions are given on the github page.

**Caveat Emptor:** I've only used this on one site so far and it's not yet released on Magento Connect because it lacks testing.

Comment: thanks @clockworkgeek  for your reply ,  but tell how i can use your post on github to slove my problem?

Comment: There is a "Download ZIP" button on that page.  Click it. When you have that ZIP extract the "app" folder from it to your Magento web folder.

Comment: ok i will add your module to my project and i will reply you about the result

Comment: @ clockworkgeek , i have installed your module and i did all the instruction in you guid but when i run my application , it gives me thie error :     Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\project-name\includes\src\__default.php on line 5504 , have you an idea about this error  ?

Comment: Yes.  You have compilation turned on which means you need to go to "System > Tools > Compilation" and click the rebuild button after installing extensions.

Comment: i can't beleive that's my probleme is solved , really i can't find any word to thank you , your module is the best module i have used in magento , thanks o lot my friend (please can you give me your email or your blog to be contected with you and follow your post)

Comment: You can follow people or projects in github.

Comment: Worked for me with a little issue, but i think it is because of sub folder. May be it will work fine on live website :). Thanks again mate

Comment: Tested on CE 1.9.2.3 with a single site and multiple store views. Seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Tested on CE 1.9.2.4 - all went fine. Thanks!