# Sub-Folder Store View - Only homepage loads

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect, nginx, server-setup

I have a store set on a different domain to my main magento installation. I then have stores in sub-folders using the second domain e.g.

- maininstall.com
- aliasdomain.com
- aliasdomain.com/store1
- aliasdomain.com/store2

etc...

Now I added the nginx code to get my aliasdomain working in the root in my .conf

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    aliasdomain.com viewcode;
    www.aliasdomain.com viewcode;
}
....
 location ~ \.php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
...
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
...
    }
```

The aliasdomain.com works fine however the subfolders do not. Basically upon opening one in browser it all works fine, but clicking onto ANY page / product in that store causes a redirect back to "aliasdomain.com" with no subfolder.

I have not added nginx configuration for these stores as there is no need they all have their own index.php with the following in:

```
$mageRunCode = 'viewcode2';
$mageRunType = 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour? I am stumped! This worked fine on Apache and I have just moved to nginx but can't see why the homepage would load (the store code is working) but then subsequent pages don't.

I have "Auto Redirect to BASE URL" set to Yes (302) in the backend (which was working fine on Apache) and if I turn it off the pages load the correct url e.g. aliasdomain.com/store1/page1 but I get a 404. Thought that was worth noting!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I just found going into the store backend and setting "Use webserver rewrites > No" fixes the issue.

The problem is I am sure I need this ticked to yes, does this narrow down where my problem lies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to figure this out, the .htaccess changes made no difference and I was stuck! I managed to figure out turning off URL rewrites for the store fixed the redirect but left /index.php/ in the URLS.

Then when looking at ways to fix this in NGINX I found some code used on wordpress in the nginx configuration which I used and it worked!

location /subfolder/ {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /subfolder/index.php?$args;
}

This allows me to keep on rewrites in the backend and also stops the homepage redirect!

Answer (score 0):

Besides `index.php`, the subdirectories also need their own `.htaccess` (or their own rewrite configuration in nginx).

Otherwise all URLs that are not pointing to a **file** (i.e. index.php), are handled by the rewrite rule of the default store.

Then for example

```
/store1/customer/account/login
```

translates to

```
/index.php/store1/customer/account/login
```

and since there is no controller for the "store1" frontend name you get redirected to the home page.

What you need is:

```
/store1/index.php/customer/account/login
```

**Related topic with more details:** [Store code in URL for every store view except for default](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/store-code-in-url-for-every-store-view-except-for-default)