# change the default store and url with store name

Tags: magento-1.9, url, store-view

i change the default store

after that URL display with store name

like this `https://example.com/ca`

the default store  URL only displayed URL

How can i remove the store name  in the URL?.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/store-code-in-url-for-every-store-view-except-for-default

Comment: only change the ` .htaccess` it remove ah?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following:

`System > Config > Web > Add Store Code to URLs`

Set to `No`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different websites I don't think you need that anyway, I think there is a setting in system < config < web Add Store Code to Urls and you should try setting that to no and then reindex.