# Multi-multistore (Multiple brands, multiple languages): setting store view code & Add Store Code to Urls

Tags: configuration, multistore, language

we have several brands in 1 Magento install. Each with different language sites.

**Our situation**

- Brand A, Brand B, brand C are set on `Store Name` level...
- Languages are set on `Store View` level
- All brands have more than 1 language: nl, de and en (set in `Store View Code`)
- Brand A and B use the `Add Store Code to Urls` setting to add /en /de etc..
- Brand C has unique root domains per country

**I have two questions that we don't know how to handle. Help appreciated.**

1. I noticed that I cannot set the `Store View Code` to EN for Brand B when there is already a `Store View Code` for Brand A; but both have EN as a language. I can imagine more Magento installs have this situation. How is this generally solved?
2. The setting `Add Store Code to Urls` is a global setting. Brand C uses a unique domain per language, whilst brand B uses the /en /de method. If I set `Add Store Code to Urls` to `YES` then it will add the store code also to the brand website that uses unique domain. Can these two methods co-exist?

Been Googling for a while now. Could not find a fitting answer.

**Thanks in advance**

---

**Images of these settings**

[image: store view names]
[image: add store code to url]

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 is answered by the fact that you must add some extra information as the storeview code needs to be unique overall.

So you need to add `brandb_en` and `brandb_nl` to those. Or something similar.
It is used to initialize the store in index.php `Mage::app('brandb_nl', 'store');`

For Question 2 you could try what happens if you put the value in the database core_config_data set to no for store C. Of coarse lets do that on a test environment, never tried it. Otherwise you should almost go with a module and a extra field as a sort of url-prefix, that you can set per storeview. Only that's a lot of work. You need to check every indexer for url's and onsave actions for products etcetera.

Comment: How about changing "Add Store Code to Urls" in the database and make it  a storename level setting (instead of global)