# Multilanguage store as symlinked subdirectory on nginx returning 'no route to page'

Tags: configuration, multistore, language, system-config

we needed to set-up our multi language store using the `subdirectory/symlink` method described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195/different-storeviews-or-websites-in-subfolders/64700#64700). (read why @ bottom)

**How we did it.** 
We copied index.php to a subdirectory and symlinked all folders. The `base url` was set to `domain.com/en`

**Problem/Question**
Now when I open domain.com/en I can see the website and it shows the English version. Only thing is that all category and product links produce a 'no route to page' error. Instead of showing the category or product. Now how can this be?

**Example**
So `https://domain.com/en/funkyshoes` does not open the category funkyshoes, and neither does funkyshoes `https://domain.com/funkyshoes` for that matter. 
`https://domain.com/en/funkyshoes` returns => `no route to page`
`https://domain.com/funkyshoes` returns => `https://domain.com/en`

---

why not? because we have more than 1 multistore and cannot give every store a lang store_code like en/de/fr & also we have one multistore with different domains per store and the other using the /en, /de, /fr method from the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even better solution is:

`location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
     }
location @rewrite {
    rewrite /(../)? /$1index.php?$args;
}`

because we had some special location rules for catalog|checkout|customer. The problem being that thay all referenced @rewrite - this way we had to rewrite ALL the location commands that were set-up to also have a separate match for /en and later /fr and /de .....

So we came up with the simplest fallback rewrite that test first for / and then for /(two-letter code) .... and rewrites based on that

seems to work fine

In addition the store_code lookup needs to be altered. Because of the /en the http_host variable or server variable do no longer work.

A possible solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078679/nginx-conf-w-multiple-maps-to-same-variable

Answer (score 0):

This is an NGINX problem.

Adding this to a conf file solved our problem

```
location /en {
 rewrite ^/en(.*)$ /en/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Hi, using this method, the pages are returned, but none of the css resolves - I have added the symlinks in the /en/ folder. any ideas?

Comment: See this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64700/78