# Custom admin path with multistore in subfolders - 404's everywhere

Tags: admin, multistore, configuration, 404

I'm dealing with a site that's had Multistore set up by using `Configuration > Web > Url options >  Add Store Code to Urls`.

Most everything works fine, except for some Modules producing 404 pages in the Administration area. For example, the MageStore Giftvoucher uses the URL `giftvoucheradmin/adminhtml_giftvoucher/index`. Our admin path is simple `/admin` so Magento is presuming that `giftvoucheradmin` is a store URL and therefore throws up a 404.

This also became a bigger issue when we switched from using `/admin` as our administration path to something more secure (eg `/new_admin_path`), and got 404's throughout the admin.

After a considerable amount of debugging I found that adding the following into a custom module config.xml file solved the issue;

```
<global>
...
<request>
        <direct_front_name>
            <new_admin_path />
        </direct_front_name>
    </request>
...
</global>
```

Now I *could* add a node into request > direct_front_name for each of the URLs used that aren't store codes, frankly though it seems like a poor solution.

Is the only other way around this to change how the stores are configured, [as outlined here by Ben Marks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212)?

Answer (score 1):

**This might be:**
Since SUPEE-6788 / 1.9.2.2 you are no longer allowed to use your own admin urls, therefore this is default behaviour.

Either you are fixing/updating the module or you set the compatibility mode introduced in the patch to active.

Comment: Not so I'm afraid. I was experiencing this on a store without this patch applied. And - that patch affects modules that use their own admin URL, NOT stores that have a different URL set in local.xml. As I understand anyway...

Answer (score 1):

As Fabian pointed out, modules should not use their own admin url's. Most modules have supplied a fix for this to make them part of the admin endpoint.

However, the admin endpoint also suffers from the issue when the `Add Store Code to Urls` config setting is enabled *and* a custom admin url is used:

- accessing the admin using `/new_admin_path` redirects to `/admin/new_admin_path/index/noRoute`
- accessing the admin using `/admin/new_admin_path` does work.

Setting the `global/request/direct_front_name/new_admin_path` XML node in a local module or in in `app/etc/local.xml` resolves this issue: it tells Magento to *not* use the store code for the custom admin endpoint.

BTW Magento also uses this setting itself for the `/xmlconnect` and `/api` endpoints, which should also be accessible without store code.