# Multi-Store Rewrites and htaccess (index.php)

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, htaccess

## Outline

I am running internationalized magento stores under sub-directories with sys-links created for every sub-directory and own index.php and .htaccess

- fashion.co.uk - default store
- fashion.com - enter page
- fashion.com/us/ - American store view
- fashion.com/eu/ - European store view
- fashion.com/au/ - Australian store view

---

## Problem

When accessing any of the internationalized stores, the URLs can not be accessed as of 404 error. When I **disable** Use Web Server Rewrites for these stores the URLs are accessible as:

- www.fashion.com/us/**index.php**/new/bras

When above is **enabled** the accessed link looks like below but 404 error appears.

- www.fashion.com/us/new/bras - **404**

---

How do I remove/rewrite the index.php from all the urls making all the links work?

---

## Structure

The 'default store' is simply under 'public_html' directory and within root I have internationalized sub-directories.

The 'default store' has:

- Add Store Code to URLs: **No**
- Auto-redirect to Base URL: **No**
- Use Web Server Rewrites: **Yes**

The 'American, European & Australian store view' has:

- Use Web Server Rewrites: **Yes**
- Base & Secure URL: **http:// www.fashion.com/us/**
- Base & Secure URL: **http:// www.fashion.com/eu/**
- Base & Secure URL: **http:// www.fashion.com/au/**
- Base URLs: **Use Website**

---

## .htaccess (Addon)

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/us/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=us_en
SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/us/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/us/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=us_en
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/us/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/eu/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=eu_en
SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/eu/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/eu/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=eu_en
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/eu/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/au/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=au_en
SetEnvIf Host www\.fashion\.com/au/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/au/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=au_en
SetEnvIf Host ^fashion\.com/au/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Answer (score 1):

This `.htaccess` can't work. `/us` and so on are not part of the **host name** (I.e. the domain)

For your desired setup it's probably the best to set "add store code to URL" to "yes"

Comment: How did this website utilise this [Website](http://bit.ly/1RNlopM) ?

Comment: Does this help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195/243

Comment: I had a look at all relevant topics and searches and can not find anything relevant.

Comment: so how can I get the urls to work under sub-dir multi-store setup?