# Magento 2 Multilanguage and Multi website with URL folder change

Tags: magento2, multistore, language, multidomain

Hi guys I come here to get some light.. I'm gonna explain what I want to do.

I want to make a base Magento 2 platform ready to be expansive with more Websites focused on **stores**.

Each websites will have multilanguage option,

- website1.es
- website1.es/**en/**
- website1.es/**pt/**

Another website...

- website2.es
- website2.es/**en/**
- website2.es/**pt/**
- ...

I added in root .htaccess the following code:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.website2\.es MAGE_RUN_CODE=**websitecode**
SetEnvIf Host www\.website2\.es MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^website2\.es MAGE_RUN_CODE=**websitecode**
SetEnvIf Host ^website2\.es MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

**The problem** is that I do not get how to use folder structure for store views. I tried to enable *Add Store Code to Urls* but Store views folders in URL are like en_1, en_2 and they are not url friendly... that's because store views code are unique.

I tried to change *Base URL*, *Base Link URL* etc options in Configuration and CSS and media loads well but the funtionality of the website is not correctly (loop of loading php and strange things)

- Base URL: website2.es/en/
- Base Link URL: website2.es/en/
- Base URL for Static View Files: website2.es/pub/static/
- Base URL for User Media Files: website2.es/pub/media/

But I don't discard to work in the future with local domains for different projects focused more on **brands** (brand3.es, brand3.fr, brand3.com ...) I comment this to get you in the case.

So I would know what do you recommend to do to take flexibility and make for now accessible to a store view by folder URL. Thanks!

**Why my post is not duplicated.**
The suggested solution is for the same domain with multiple magento websites.
My request is different and propose a different flexibility. Mine is Magento2 and their 1.x

Comment: cause your base now moved so per every subfolder you must have proper rewrite, no need any actual folders on the server, 
never tried that with apache, but something like this:
`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^pt/.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE=D1_es_pt`
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different storeviews or websites in subfolders](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195/different-storeviews-or-websites-in-subfolders)

Comment: Look for the "languagefolders" answer in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @MagenX Thanks a lot I'm gonna try it, but how recognize that request_URI the domain ? Maybe I sould use "^website2.es/pt/."?

Comment: @fschmengler Hi I have read it but I saw that they were talking about Enterprise Edition. Anyway I have been expected that their solution was a little tricky and not very stable (I don't want to start duplicating files...)

Comment: be careful with subfolders, make sure your `.htaccess` protects it too as root folder

Comment: @MagenX the SetEnvIf that you attached is for pt domain or pt folder? I should try with MAGE_CORE_TYPE=website or store? I'm not getting anything successfully...

Comment: Hi @MagenX I'm new in Stackexchange, could I suggest you to remove the possible duplicate? Is not the same case, they use the same domain for all and my idea is to have a lot of multiple domains. Regards!

Comment: all the same issue... you either configure store code in apache or index.php

Comment: @MagenX is not man.. they are walking always in 1 domain.. they use /en folder for just 1 domain.. how can you set 1 request URI for multiple host access? For example:

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^pt/.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE=D1_es_pt

How can apache know the domain? www.website1.com/pt (D1_es_pt) or www.website2.com/pt (D2_es_pt) ?

Comment: do you have any php or server configuration knowledge? we gave you so many hints, we can not build website for you...

Comment: @MagenX not at this level for sure. I'm progressing, I created a folder pt and copy root .htaccess & index.php to this folder. Then I added SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.com MAGE... but I must create symlink (I read that is not secure...) or modify magento rewrite folder in the .htaccess from pt because outputs an error of bootstrap path.

Anyway I would like to say that thanks a lot.