# Using URL subfolders for multi-language Store Views in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, store-view, seo, language, magento-community

I configured Magento 2 with two Store Views in order to have two front-end languages (English and Italian) and I would like to have the following behaviour:

```
http://example.com/     -->  Store View "English" (code = "en") - Default
http://example.com/it/  -->  Store View "Italian" (code = "it")
```

That is, the English Store View should be available on standard urls and the Italian Store View should be available within the "it" subfolder in the url. Nothing strange, a common configuration for multilanguage websites.

I found here a quite similar question regarding Magento 1.x: [Different storeviews or websites in subfolders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195/different-storeviews-or-websites-in-subfolders). But since the accepted answer is not trivial (it involves rewrites in the `.htaccess` and modifications in the `index.php`), I would like to ask if with Magento 2 there is a simpler way to get this done?

---

#### UPDATE

Premise: I don't mind about having multiple websites so I don't have the problem to having several websites with the same languages (that [would be a problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197/38275) for the below solution).

So I enabled the `Add Store Code to Urls` option, from *Configuration > Web > Url > Add Store Code to Urls*, and it's working good. But now I have duplicated urls for the default language (English):

```
http://example.com/     -->  Store View "English" (code = "en")
http://example.com/en/  -->  Store View "English" (code = "en")
http://example.com/it/  -->  Store View "Italian" (code = "it")
```

Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. avoid the subfolder in the url for the default language?

Answer (score 11):

I ended up in using the below solution. I saw it is a quite common configuration for multi-language Magento websites.

This solution provides a default language with a redirect from "normal" url (urls without lang subfolder) to urls with the default lang subfolder.

For example, if `it` is the default language, it happen this:

```
example.com/         -->  example.com/it/
example.com/contact  -->  example.com/it/contact
...
```

#### 1) Create store views with lang code

- Go to *Stores > All Stores*.
- Create a *Store View* for each language.
- Set in the *Code* field the language code.
- Example: I have two store views, *Italiano* with code *"it"* (default view) and *English* with code *en*.

#### 2) Enable the *Add Store Code to Urls* option

- From *Stores > Configurations > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls > Yes*.
- Enabling this option I have the following:

  ```
  http://example.com/it/  -->  Store View "Italian" (code = "it")
  http://example.com/en/  -->  Store View "English" (code = "en")
  ```

#### 3) Set a default language redirect in the .htaccess

Open the `.htaccess` and search for these lines:

```
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Then place the following lines just **before** the above ones:

```
############################################
## redirects for urls without lang dir to default lang (it)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(it|en|admin\w*|soap|rest)($|/.*$)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [L,R=301]
```

These lines will redirect all urls without language subfolder to the same url with default subfolder `/it` at the beginning:

```
example.com/contact  -->  example.com/it/contact
```

Urls starting with `en/`, `admin`, `soap/`, `rest/` are not redirected.

You can customize it, changing the default language subfolder and adding other ignored urls (at least one for each language code you have).

#### 4) Redirect the root to default language subdir

In the `.htaccess` search for these lines:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
```

Then place the following lines just **after**:

```
############################################
## redirect root to default lang (it)

    RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /it/
```

#### Drawbacks

I used this solution and it's working good for me. The only really drawback I have experienced is that the `.htaccess` is rewritten each time I update Magento, so I have to restore it after the updating.

Another drawback can be if you have a multiple website configuration and several websites with the same languages as pointed out in a comment to this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197/38275

Answer (score 0):

I have question. Let's say I have two urls under one admin (Magento 2):
1) www.abc.cz - runs only Czech version
2) www.cde.com - currently runs EN version

I want to have more Store view under .com for example: .com/de , .com/es etc. but I don't want to have "folder system" for EN language which runs directly under .com .

If I understand correctly from someone, when I start using folder system for .com, the .cz version will be affected and create .cz/cz folder which is undesirable for me.

How to do that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, there is setting in magento admin under configuration to set if you want suffix store or not.