# How to set up multistore and multilanguage configuration?

Tags: magento2, multistore, language

I want to setup up two stores on one installation. Both stores shall be available in English and German.

I want them to be available at the following example urls:

1. Store: Engineering (German: Maschinenbau)
   English Store View: https://www.example.com/engineering/en/
   German Store View: https://www.example.com/maschinenbau/de/
2. Store: Industry (German: Industrie)
   English Store View: https://www.example.com/industry/en/
   German Store View: https://www.example.com/industie/de/

Via `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web` I selected each of the four store views and entered the aforementioned URLs in the `Base URL` and `Base Link URL` input fields.

The problem is: Now the frontend is broken. No matter what url I enter it always returns a 404. The 404 page comes as plain html, no css is applied.

I furthermore have a question: When I enter https://www.example.com it currently redirects me to the first store view https://www.example.com/engineering/en/. What do I have to change if I want to remain on https://www.example.com/ and get a page that lets the customers select between the two stores: Engineering and Industry?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one store and his store view for each, then you go to `Stores > Configuration > general > Locale` and set the right laguage for each store view to do that you have on the top left the storeview scope.

To switch between stores, you have to add `?___store=yourStoreViewCode`after domaine for exemple `www.domaine.com?___store=fr`

About the **store switcher**, it must appear automatically because now you will create them as I said well before.

**Store switcher** it appear JUST when you have 2 store views or more under the current website that you are viewing.

**Edit:**

if you want that your url becomes `domaine.com/en` or `domaine.com/de` you have to set that in `Unsecure url` and `Secure url`, don't forget to change the storeview scope, And you need to do some mapping for these urls in `.htaccess`or `index.php`, you can follow these [tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128286/using-url-subfolders-for-multi-language-store-views-in-magento-2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to make use of url queries when switching between store views. I want to have different url paths since this is better for SEO.

Comment: Look my edit please

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's not working. I am getting a 404 when I type in the url that I entered in Unsecure or secure url. I followed the tutorial but I think it does not apply to my problem since its written for M1. I use M2.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that you're using M2, look again my edit, i changed the tutorial link

Comment: The tutorial is not about having multiple stores within one domain. This is my issue. I have looked at Google but it seems that there is no tut on this even though I think this is a common problem.