# Country specific Url in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create two different Url in Magento in order to be able to show different prices for the same product. eg: http://example.com/uk and http://example.com/de.

Comment: see this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195/146

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Magento Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Web Tab
   And change "Add Store Code to Urls" to "Yes"
2. Change code of store views to "uk" and "de" in System > Manage Stores
3. Make re-index and flush cache.